# Get/Read Public Certificate for PDF Encryption using .pfx file with password through itext7 library/method

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext7, x509certificate2

I have iText7 functions which I am using,

right now, I am trying to encrypt my PDF file using a certificate in .pfx format with password.

The thing is, the function cannot read .pfx because it does not provide the password as shown below

```
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

namespace iText.Samples.Sandbox.Security
{
    public class EncryptWithCertificate
    {
        public static readonly String DEST = "results/sandbox/security/encrypt_with_certificate.pdf";
        public static readonly String SRC = "../../../resources/pdfs/hello.pdf";
        public static readonly String PUBLIC = "../../../resources/encryption/test.cer";

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();

            new EncryptWithCertificate().ManipulatePdf(DEST);
        }

        public X509Certificate GetPublicCertificate(String path)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
                X509Certificate readCertificate = parser.ReadCertificate(stream);
                return readCertificate;
            }
        }

        protected void ManipulatePdf(String dest)
        {
            // The file created by this example can not be opened, unless
            // you import the private key stored in test.p12 in your certificate store.
            // The password for the p12 file is kspass.
            X509Certificate cert = GetPublicCertificate(PUBLIC);

            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest,
                new WriterProperties().SetPublicKeyEncryption(
                    new[] {cert},
                    new[] {EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING},
                    EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256)));
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If i try to load a normal .cer file, it goes through normally for `GetPublicCertificate`. No issue there. But I am trying to encrypt it with .pfx file as adobe acrobat can only register Digital ID using .p12/.pkf format and the function does throws error.

The error

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Security.Certificates.CertificateException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Message=Failed to read certificate
      
    
    Inner Exception 1:
    ArgumentException: Unknown object in GetInstance: Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger
    Parameter name: obj
```

I am hoping to encrypt the pdf using cert as the cert can be set to expire anytime according to what I set it to be and user can only view the PDF file based on the cert expiry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your final goal? Restrict access to PDS based on cert validity? Then your solution is completely wrong. From very beginning to very end.

Comment: Yes @Crypt32, The end goal is to add restriction to the PDF. Only users with the cert can open the PDF.I also manage to create a ".pfx", right now I just want to encrypt the cert to the selected PDF. May I know why my solution is completely wrong as per what you said? Thank you ^_^

Comment: Because you cannot set time restrictions. User can access the PDF as long as it possesses the private key. Cert expiry doesn't play any role here. Your solution is equivalent to password-based encryption. And keep in mind that once user gets PDF unencrypted, user can save unencrypted PDF and get unlimited access even without cert and private key.

Comment: I see @Crypt32. I have tried to implement the javascript for password-based encryption and expiry date access restriction on PDF. the only thing is, the file can be opened in Viewer such as Google Chrome, Firefox (Browser) which defeat the purpose. So I am trying for this solution as I noticed that the cert can set an expiry date. If you have a better solution, I do appreciate your reply and suggestion ^_^.

Comment: you cannot set expire time based on certs, it is kind of irrelevant. I would look at RMS (rights management services) solutions that are intended to solve exact problem.

Comment: @Crypt32 Okay, I will look at RMS for this, thanks again for your time! Appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Crypt32, I just had an idea....If i encrypt the PDF with the cert while at the same time...implement javascript to embed a time expiry checking....will that work? As the cert can be used to restrict user from opening in any browser pdf viewer...while the javascript may have certain security, limitation....just an idea...I tried looking up the RMS...not much that can integrate to C#....urghh

Comment: Keep in mind that client is able to manipulate the time on a machine and break your restrictions. You need an external control system (which is provided by RMS) that will make decision if requested operation is allowed and how long it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As per your original post, your intention is:

> I am hoping to encrypt the pdf using cert as the cert can be set to expire anytime according to what I set it to be and user can only view the PDF file based on the cert expiry.

Basically, you want to grant a time-limited access to PDF to authorized user. The solution you try to build in code sample doesn't solve the problem. Certificate validity for data encryption is irrelevant, because certificate validity is not checked during decryption. In fact, even certificate is not necessary, it is sufficient to have just a private key to decrypt the data. In other words, certificate-based encryption is equal to password-based encryption. What certificate adds -- an easier way to locate decryption key (secret), nothing else.

In addition, once data is decrypted, a client can save data in an unencrypted form thus your restrictions are useless. Even if you try to put time constraints within JavaScript or whatever else locally (and JavaScript is executed only locally), it isn't a solution. As long as client can manipulate date/time on a device, client always can set desired date/time to violate your restrictions.

Your problem cannot be solved without inventing a 3rd party entity that will make decisions whether the requested operation is allowed, apply necessary restrictions and minimize chances that the data will leak in an unencrypted form (only minimize, not prevent). Such functionality is implemented in [Digital Rights Management (DRM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) or Rights Management Service (RMS) and you need to build your solution around these tools, not attempt to integrate them in your solution. There are plenty of vendors that offer DRM/RMS solutions you can look into and utilize their functionality to build the solution for your requirements.

Comment: *"In other words, certificate-based encryption is equal to password-based encryption."* - Well, it is equal as far as usefulness for the OP's task is concerned. In general it's not equal of course.